# how to change autocomplete from ajax results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I made a simple text box to take a user input. I pass that info to a PHP page through ajax (on each input) to get a result.  I can display those results in a DIV below the input box, but I can't manage to change the autocomplete results.

MY JS CODE:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" >
<div id="test"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var availableTags = null;

$('#search').on('input', function() {

        var input_txt = $('#search').val();

          $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_search.php",
            method: "get",
            data: { input: input_txt },
            success: changeInput

            });
});


function changeInput(content){
    $("#test").html(content);

    availableTags = content;

    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
}


</script>
```

MY PHP of (ajax_search.php)

```
$input = $_GET['input'];

if(!empty($input))
{
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE :input');
$stmt->execute(array('input' => $input.'%'));


while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
        echo $row['city']."<br>";
    }

}
```

I can't figure how to handle the results to pass them to the source of autocomplete.  Thanks

Comment: what is the exact problem

Comment: @Shi-ii I can't get my AJAX results into the AUTOCOMPLETE of my input text

Comment: **availableTags** contains an array right?

Comment: @Sahil  I don't think so... how do I pass the AJAX result into a JS array?

Comment: Your right @user3011784

Comment: Just try running this in console and see if it works, `$("#search").autocomplete({
        source: ["Apple","Mango"]
    });`

Comment: @Sahil no, it's not working,  I disabled everything except this line, and it's not working. Using Chrome... weird

Comment: JQuery UI can i use that

Comment: give `console.log(content)` inside changeInput function, to check what value is getting returned from backend.

Comment: @Sahil Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that [`autocomplete` `source` property requires an array](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) as an input, and you appear to be passing HTML. You might be able to use split to convert it:

```
availableTags = content.split("<br>");
$("#search").autocomplete( "option", "source", availableTags); //<==jquery docs suggest this method
$("#search").autocomplete({ source: availableTags }); //<==OP suggests this works
```

**update**

If you want to use jQuery autocomplete in your code then you need to include the code files for jQuery UI. I see your already using Google hosted library. You can go back there and find the correct libraries to include [for jQuery UI](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui). By the way, you need the CSS and JS files.

Comment: it's not working, but even if I try this:  var availableTags = ["11", "22", "33"];  It doesn't work either, so there might be another problem as well

Comment: Hey i tryed that it works and i was also going to post it.

Comment: @user3011784 Hey it looks like there is a special way that is required to update the source. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Or should I say this is the method shown in the documentation on the jQuery UI website (which I linked to above)

Comment: I can't seem to get a basic test to work, see my jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/mib92/enud16nq/2/

Comment: my console says:    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: ok, thanks, I've added the jQuery UI and CSS and it doesn't work with the ("option", ... )  but it works like this:  $("#search").autocomplete(
{
        source: availableTags
    });

Comment: @user3011784 Ok! Thanks for the info. I have updated my answer to include more detail on that.